# Aframe animation mixer play animation programatically

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I have an animated gltf model and i would like to only trigger the animation once something happens, but i can't find any [documentation](https://github.com/n5ro/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/loaders) about triggering the animation programatically or even how to prevent it from playing immediately.

The entity:

```
<a-entity gltf-model="#info-1" animation-mixer="clip: *; loop: once; clampWhenFinished: true;" position="0.4 -0.8 0" scale="0.3 0.3 0.3"></a-entity>
```

Any idea how i can prevent it from playing the animation right away and play it programatically once i want to?

I'm guessing it can be done by using directly Three.js?

Answer (score 4):

When defining `animation-mixer` component you can set the `timeScale` property to `0` which will pause before starting.
Then when you are ready set `timeScale` to `1.0` (or whatever speed you would like).

```
<a-entity id="animatedmodel" gltf-model="#info-1" animation-mixer="clip: *; loop: once; clampWhenFinished: true;" position="0.4 -0.8 0" scale="0.3 0.3 0.3"></a-entity>
```

Then

```
document.getElementById("animatedmodel").setAttribute('animation-mixer','timeScale: 1.0;');
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up doing as a workaround to add the `animation-mixer` attribute only when i want to start the animation.

I'd still be curious to know if there is a better way to do this so if you know please post an answer.